# Updated Azure Data Factory Pipeline parameters not recognized After creation and attaching

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline `Pipeline_A` and this pipeline has an Array parameter called `sourceTables`

The pipeline works properly and is attached to trigger `Trigger_A` and runs every day successfully

The problem: When I update my parameter, `sourceTables`, say I add a new table to the array, The Pipeline doesn't include the new changes :(

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Initially, the trigger had parameters of it's own for the pipeline, so I removed the parameters from the trigger.

Comment: Hi, have you published the pipeline after changes?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT Yes I did, but it did not work. Also initially the problem was that my trigger had parameters of it's own, so I removed the parameters from the trigger. But I'm still having the same problem

Comment: @JohanKhanye Can u access your parameters using pipeline().parameters.parametername  ?? 
if so then the problem is in the pipeline and not in the new added params.

Comment: @Johan Khanye, I have repro'd and had no issues with trigger/pipeline parameters even after updating the array pipeline parameter value. Can you share more details on how you are using this parameter value inside the pipeline and where you are not seeing the updated value?

Comment: I'm not sure, how I was having that problem, but I replaced my pipeline parameters with Global parameters and replaced my trigger with a new one, and now it behaves properly. thank you for your assistance